# Why pad the stack on a function call?

Tags: c++, macos, assembly

I was looking at the dissasembly of a function call and found this:

```
movq    %rsp, %rbp
pushq   %rbx
subq    $136, %rsp        ; Pad the stack
....
addq    $136, %rsp        ; Unpad the stack
popq    %rbx
popq    %rbp
ret
```

What is the value of doing this?

Comment: Faster access on appropriate memory address boundaries (as with any padding).

Comment: Oh, as in accessing memory by offset is faster than accessing it by performing `push`es?

Comment: I presume they are reserving space for local variables with function scope. Afterwards, you have to place the stack pointer at the right place in order not to disturb the stack frame (to return to the right spot in the program).

Comment: It will also prevent small buffer overflows from corrupting the return address and the saved frame pointer, which in turn makes debugging a lot easier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's the space for local variables, not padding.

The compiler will create that stack space for any register spills and local variables it has to store while running this function.

You could see some padding, when disassembling x86-64 code with the SysV ABI (most things that aren't Windows, I don't know how it is in the latter), since function calls have to have the stack aligned at 16 bytes. But in this case it's actually reserving space for local variables.

You might want to look at [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames#Standard_Entry_Sequence) or look for more information on how compilers work.